# Handling multiple saved game data-instances in MySQL

Tags: database-design, mysql

I'm building my first ever web-based game in PHP/MySQL and I'am having difficulty conceptualising how to deal with saved game data instances. It's a football manager game with tables like...

```
players, managers, matches, results, injuries, stadiums, leagues etc
```

My problem is that some of those tables need to hold completely different data for each saved game and I don't know the best way to handle saving multiple instances of all game data.

What is the most elegant way to handle this? Should I create a totally unique set of transactional tables every time a new game is created? e.g. if I have 1000 games, they're be 1000 different variations of the "results" table? The only other rather ugly database-design solution I can think of doing is having a game_id column in every table that varies game-by-game.

Or is there some other technology outside of the database layer that better caters for coping with a potentially large number of different instances of the same data? The best match I could find for this question on StackOverflow was How do games handle saved content?, but it's a pretty old post and doesn't completely address my problem. Thanks for any thoughts at all.

Comment: What've you got so far? I mean an ER diagram. Also the question has nothing to do with MySQL.

Comment: please don't **[cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info "'Cross-posting is frowned upon...'")**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44864199/handling-multiple-saved-game-data-instances-in-mysql "Cross-posting is frowned upon as it leads to fragmented answers splattered all over the network..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a Game table and a GameId column to relevant tables. then you can have multiple games at the same time.